# How can I get an animation between two 3d points and one orientation matrix

Tags: 3d, rotation

Ok, the first this is the thing, I have two 3dpoints(A,B) I want to rotate B with center A in an euler angle. For example:

```
A = (0 0 0).
B = (2 0 0).
eulerAngle = (PI 0 0).
```

with this information the new position for B should be (-2 0 0). I can get the orientation matrix between A and B, and I can use the euler angle in this orientation matrix, to get the new orientation matrix but i down know how can i get the new B's position

Comment: How can I get the new B position.

Answer (score 0):

Euler angles are not really suited for interpolation.
Trying to do it this way will be painful and the performance cost will be overkill.
Instead you should look into Quaternions.

Comment: What you can do is convert your Euler coordinates to Quads then do the interpolation. Once done convert back to Euler.

Comment: thank you for your advice, i been working this project [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mctbza5qfcdxbs3/Roassal3dtutorial.pdf) and i want to use it with some animations

Comment: It seems like you should first implement linear algebra, matrices and quads into it before you handle the rest (that's usually called a Node system). It might seem hard but it is what every engine does before offering advanced options (such a mesh loading, animations, texturing etc...).